# PHP MYSQL date, time, datetime and timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I new to PHP and confused with date, time, datetime and timestamp. I have a MYSQL table contains date, time, datetime and timestamp.

Whats the format to use from PHP to MYSQL fields?

```
    sql_timestamp = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
    $date_conv = new DateTime($this->sql_timestamp);
    sql_date = $date_conv->format('Y-m-d');
    sql_time = $date_conv->format('H:i:s');
    sql_datetime =  gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); ??? I am confused here
```

I dont see different between DATETIME and Timestamp assignment ? Could anyone help what i need to keep in these four fields? Thank you

Comment: timestamp and datetime have the same format.  There are some behavioral differences as pointed out in the answer by Jacob S below and the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about MySQL:

TIMESTAMP is, essentially, a DATETIME that is automatically converted to UTC when stored by MySQL and automatically adjusted for the timezone of specified to the MySQL connection. TIMESTAMP also has a smaller date storage range than DATETIME.

See the [MySQL manual on this topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) for more information.